# Is ALSA's asym plugin deprecated?

Tags: audio, alsa, alsamixer

I have a Logitech Webcam C310 and the built-in microphone of the webcam works
really well, that's why I use at as my default microphone.

My `~/.asoundrc` looks like this:

```
pcm.usb
{
    type hw
    card U0x46d0x81b
}

pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmix"
    }
    capture.pcm 
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmix"
    }
    capture.pcm 
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
}
```

This setup has been working well for the last couple of years.

I use Gentoo Linux and last week I made an system wide update. I didn't pay
attention whether `media-libs/alsa-lib` and/or `media-plugins/alsa-plugins`
got updated but when I executed `alsamixer` I got the following error:

```
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.1.2/work/alsa-lib-1.1.2/src/dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib64/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_asym.so
 cannot open mixer: No such device or address
```

My current version of `media-libs/alsa-lib` is 1.1.2 and the version of
`media-plugins/alsa-plugins` is 1.1.1-r1. I've downloaded the sources of both
and compilied them but the file `libasound_module_ctl_asym.so` is never
generated.

Is the `asym` module deprecated? Which option in `./configure` should I enable
in order to compile and link `libasound_module_ctl_asym.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asym` plugin is a PCM plugin; it is not possible to apply it to `ctl` devices.

This configuration has never worked.
If you did not get this error before, then it probably got overridden by a later definition somewhere else.

Remove that `ctl` `asym` definition. You'll have to select the respective sound device in `alsamixer` (as you probably already did).

Comment: thanks for answer. Hmm, I'm curious then why stuff like `alsamixer` never complained about this. When I wanted to set my default microphone, I googled it and found this configuration. I don't remember which site. So, only the last part `ctl.!default...` in incorrect then?

Comment: The reason why I needed to write my own `asoundrc` was that Skype switched to `pulseaudio`. I don't like `pulseaudio` and I had to use `apulse` to emulate `pulseaudio`. Skype itself did not give me a choice for the microphone selection and `apulse` itself (at least at that time) used the default input and output.